# Managing Custom Code Modifications for Wordpress Plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, version-control

The number of custom modifications I am making to popular existing plugins has been growing to the point where managing them has been difficult. I have kept a list of what insertions or edits I have made in what files at what lines, but this is a bit cumbersome.

The problem comes when I upgrade my plugins and it overwrites my changes which I need to re-apply.

Does anyone have an automated or at least, managed approach to this kind of code merging problem?

I feel like there is a GIT solution here, but I am not clear how it would be setup.

Comment: I don't have any experience with WordPress, but this does sound like a frustrating problem.  Certainly, Git can keep track of changes to plugins you make, but then the mechanism for updating the plugins exists externally to Git, so that's going to be a huge headache.  I can envision a workflow where you update your plugin and then create a tag in your repository indicating what version the plugin is.  When you need to update the plugin again, you can diff against the last tag to see what changes need to be applied to the new version....